# Batch file to boot to desktop on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, batch

I wanted to put a batch file that runs `explorer.exe` on a scheduled task so it would run every time I log on and boot me right to the desktop. I know there's 3rd party programs that do this and so does Windows 8.1. But I want to do it my own way just for the satisfaction of doing something my own way.

But can it even be done with a batch file?

Because when I log on, it boots to the desktop but then it starts file explorer too. And when I look at task manager it seems like file explorer is tied into windows explorer. I was going to just to `taskkill (pid of file explorer)` but there is no pid for file explorer, only windows explorer.

Comment: *"when I log on, it boots to desktop but then it starts file explorer too"* -- what did you do for that? Simply run `explorer.exe`? (As an aside: upgrading to Windows 8.1, if possible, also gets you the new Internet Explorer, and maybe other Microsoft updates. I didn't know it could boot into the desktop though.)

Comment: Can you try `start "" "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954041/restarting-explorer-exe-only-opens-an-explorer-window/23889433#23889433)?

Comment: That's all I did. I made a batch file with nothing but
explorer.exe and exit inside of it. But file explorer manages to come up along with the desktop. I was going to upgrade to 8.1 eventually it just hasn't been much of a concern to me. 
I'll try out that link though.
EDIT. I tried the link. Putting in start "" "C:\Windows\explorer.exe still brought up file explorer.

Comment: Another aside, in case you didn't know: hitting Win+D from the Windows 8 tiles also shows the desktop. So maybe searching for emulating that helps, if no answers are posted here.

Comment: Not a batch file, but maybe it helps: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/bypass-windows-8-start-screen-to-jump-directly-to-desktop-on-startup/, which uses `C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}`